# Docker is extremely slow when running Laravel on Nginx container wsl2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

I've updated Windows 10 to 2004 latest version, installed wsl2 and updated it, installed docker, and ubuntu.

When I create a simple *index.php* file with "Hello World" it's working perfectly ( response: 100-400ms ) but when I added my *Laravel* project it becomes miserable as it loads for **7sec** before performing the request and the response is **4 - 7 seconds**, even though *PHPMyAdmin* is running very smoothly (  response: 1 - 2 seconds ).

my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3.8'
networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
      - phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    image: node:latest
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

I've been trying to fix this issue for 2 days but couldn't find the answer.

Thanks

Comment: Did this not happen when you weren't using WSL 2? You could try disabling WSL 2 integration in Docker Desktop and check if the issue still persists. That would at least show whether the problem lies with WSL 2 or not.

Comment: I believe it was slightly better with hyper-v (before installing wsl2), but when I run PHPMyAdmin it works perfectly so maybe the problem is within the Laravel files as it asks me for sharing these files every time I build docker-compose.

Comment: Ahh, I maybe see what could be going wrong. Are you mounting your files from the windows file system? It could result in very poor i/o.

Comment: Same issue here. Have you found an answer?

Comment: Same issue here. Laravel 14sec (mounted from windows) loading vs 500ms(copied to container). In this case we reinvented the wheel. I mounted network drive as file system 15 years ago and had same performance....

Comment: Did you fix it? How?, please share it

Answer (score 38):

It looks like you are mounting your Laravel project in your container. This could result in very poor file I/O if you are mounting these files from your Windows environment to WSL 2, since WSL 2 currently has a lot of problems accessing files that are on the Windows environment. This I/O issue exists as of July 2020, you can find the ongoing status of the issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197).

There are three possible solutions I can think of that will resolve this issue for now.

---

**Disable WSL 2 based engine for docker until the issue is resolved**

Since this issue only occurs when WSL 2 tries to access the Windows filesystem, you could choose to disable WSL 2 docker integration and run your containers on your Windows environment instead. You can find the option to disable it in the UI of Docker Desktop here:
[image]

---

**Store your project in the Linux filesystem of WSL 2**

Again, since this issue occurs when WSL 2 tries to access the mount points of the Windows filesystem under `/mnt`, you could choose to store your project onto the Linux filesystem of WSL 2 instead.

---

**Build your own Dockerfiles**

You could choose to create your own Dockerfiles and instead of mounting your project, you can `COPY` the desired directories into the docker images instead. This would result in poor build performance, since WSL 2 will still have to access your Windows filesystem in order to build these docker images, but the runtime performance will be much better, since it won't  have to retrieve these files from the Windows environment everytime.

Comment: Tried to copy project files to `mnt/wsl` but failed (**can't read from the source file or disk**) the same thing when I copy to images containers, I ended up disabling wsl2 and removing ubuntu. :(

Comment: Your WSL filesystem isn't under `mnt/WSL`. It's that entire filesystem itself.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on
"Store your project in WSL 2"
How can I do it?

Comment: @user3529607 Within WSL you have the Linux filesystem (e.g. directory `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04`) and the Windows filesystem as a mount point (e.g. `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\mnt\c`). In a nutshell, place your project files somewhere other than a subdirectory of `/mnt/`, otherwise there is a good chance you will place your project files within the Windows filesystem, which is what causes the bad IO.

Comment: How this disabled on windows 10 home?

Comment: Can some one explain all the above steps in an easy matter/words

Comment: Points 2 and 3 are fine for _running_ applications but what about _developing_ applications on Windows? Do we have to edit, save, and copy the file into the container each time? Sticking with option 1 until they have this resolved.

Comment: Disable WSL 2 based engine works for me, thanks !

Comment: @waterloomatt I'm not following completely. Point 2 and 3 shouldn't require you to edit, save and copy files into a container each time. Point 2 is just as simple as moving your project to a different directory and continuing to develop from there, although you will probably need an editor that supports developing in WSL to continue working (e.g. VSCode). Point 3 uses the COPY instruction in your Dockerfile, so you aren't copying files manually.

Comment: Disabling WSL2 works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried point 2 , moved the files but after updating my docker-compose file with the new path the files seems to not be visible anymore by windows docker installation and i get an empty folder and cannot execute the project anymore. any hint ?

Comment: Disabling WSL2 docker engine and enabling Hyper-V in windows 10 pro edition, worked for me, thanks. :-)

Comment: Hm...so what if the wsl2 option is "always-on" i.e. greyed out and ticked on?  What is preventing switching off the option?

Comment: If the WSL2 option is "always-on" that means you don't have hyper-v available. Probably running Home edition of Windows. (If hyper-v is not turned on in windows features then it will give you a error, instead, when you turn off that option.)

Answer (score 10):

You just move all source project to folder

```
\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\<User Name>\<Project Name>
```

The speed will be to very fast such run on Linux Native

#### Before

[image: Before]

#### After

[image: After]

Comment: I copied the files and updated my docker-compose in this way /var/www:/var/web/www:rw  but they files seems not to be linked between docker windows and ubuntu. the folder in docker looks to be empty

Comment: i disabled WSL2 in Docker for Windows and  got the same effect. 7,5s vs 1,7s. Linux Mint native docker time is 0,8s.

Comment: @zardoz So you don't get a power of wsl

Comment: thanks buddy finally someone resolve my problem

Answer (score 6):

You are running your project on the `/mnt/xxx` folder, isn't it?

This is because [wsl2 filesystem performance is much slower than wsl1 in /mnt.](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197)

If you want a very short solution, it is here. Works on Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian from windows store:

1. Go to the docker settings and turn on `Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS` and turn off `Use the WSL 2 based engine`.
2. Run this command:

```bash
clear && sudo apt-get update && \
sudo curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && sudo sh get-docker.sh && sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && \
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
echo "export PATH=\"$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin\"" >> ~/.profile && source ~/.profile && \
echo "export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc && \
printf '[automount]\nroot = /\noptions = metadata' | sudo tee -a /etc/wsl.conf
```

I wrote the instruction on how to integrate the Docker Desktop with WSL 1 here:
https://github.com/CaliforniaMountainSnake/wsl-1-docker-integration

Comment: Had to downgrade from wsl2 to wsl1 with hyper-v and spent hours trying various fixes. These are the only instructions that worked. Life saving!

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so i got an interesting fact :))

Running docker on windows without WSL2.

A request has TTFB 5.41s. This is the index.php file. I used die() to check where the time is bigger and i found that if i use die() after terminate, the TTFB becomes ~2.5s.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require __DIR__.'/../../application/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../application/bootstrap/app.php';

#die(); <-- TTFB 1.72s
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

#die(); <-- TTFB 2.67s

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

#die(); <-- TTFB 2.74s

#if there is no die in the file then TTFB is ~6s
```

Comment: I found the same thing in our project. I have no idea why `die()` does anything but it took our nginx + php stack from 6s per response to 200ms per response.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue with Laravel/Docker/Nginx on Windows 11.

I couldn't disable "Use the WSL 2 based engine", because it was grey out, even after installing Hyper-v on Windows 11 Home (tweak).

**Here is the best solution I found:**

**1 . Copy your project into your WSL folder**

- Open Windows explorer and type the following address :
  \**wsl.localhost**\
- Select your WSL instance, and then you can copy your project into **/home/yourUsername/**

The full URL will be something like :
\**wsl.localhost\ubuntu\home\username\yourProject**

**2.Start docker containers**

Just open a terminal from this folder, and start your containers

eg: docker-compose up -d

**3.Visual Studio Code**

*to open the project folder from visual studio :*
CTRL + P, >Remote-WSL : Open folder in WSL...

*to open the project folder from  the command line :*
code --remote wsl+Ubuntu /home/username/yourProject

Comment: This has improved the performarnce greatly. But i also have to limit the memory that docker uses otherwise it eats all the ram and the system goes slow

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude `vendor` folder from compose file
like

```
    volumes:
  - ./www:/var/www
  - vendor:/var/www/vendor
```

Comment: I excluded vendor from mounted volumes and it started running fast againg for me. It's a bit pain that I have different vendor in host and inside docker container, but it's good wnough workaround imho.

Answer (score 1):

This is really sketchy way of improving the speed but here is goes:

## Problem

The speed of loading composer dependencies from a `vendor` dir, which is mapped from project root on Windows to a docker container via WSL 2, is currently reaaaaaly slow.

## Solution

Copy vendor dir to docker image and use it as opposed to the mapped one in project root.

The project structure using MySQL database and Apache PHP 7.4 with composer auto-loading looks like this:

```
db
    - init.sql
dev
    - db
        - Dockerfile
        - data.sql
    - www
        - Dockerfile
        - vendor-override.php
    - docker-compose.yaml
src
    - ...
vendor
    - ...
composer.json
index.php
...
```

The idea here is to keep dev stuff separated from the main root dir.

### dev/docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  test-db:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: dev/db/Dockerfile

  test-www:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: dev/www/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - {insert_random_port_here}:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/html
```

Here we have two services, one for MySQL database and one for Apache with PHP, which maps web root `/var/www/html` to our project root. This enables Apache to see the project source files (`src` and `index.php`).

### dev/db/Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:5.7.24

# Add initialize script (adding 0 in front of it, makes sure it is executed first as the scripts are loaded alphabetically)
ADD db/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0init.sql

# Add test data (adding 99 infront of it, makes sure it is executed last)
ADD dev/db/data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/99data.sql
```

### dev/www/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.0-apache-buster

# Install PHP extensions and dependencies required by them
RUN apt-get update -y & \
    apt-get install -y libzip-dev libpng-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev & \
    docker-php-ext-install gd json pdo pdo_mysql mysqli ftp simplexml curl

# Enable apache mods and .htaccess files
RUN a2enmod rewrite & \
    sed -e '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' -i /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Add composer to improve loading speed since its located inside linux
ADD vendor /var/www/vendor
ADD dev/www/vendor-override.php /var/www/
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www & \
    mkdir /var/www/html/src & \
    ln -s /var/www/html/src /var/www/src

# Expose html dir for easier deployments
VOLUME /var/www/html
```

I'm using official Apache buster image with PHP 7.4.

1. Here we copy `vendor` dir and `vendor-override.php` to a dir above the webroot (`/var/www`) so it doesn't interfere with project root.

```
ADD vendor /var/www/vendor
ADD dev/www/vendor-override.php /var/www/
```

2. Next we set the read write execute permissions for everybody so Apache can read it. This necessary because its outside the webroot.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

3. Now the trick here is to make sure the composer auto-loads classes from `src` dir. This is solved by creating a link from `/var/www/src/` to `/var/www/html/src` which is in our project root.

```
mkdir /var/www/html/src
ln -s /var/www/html/src /var/www/src
```

### dev/www/vendor-override.php

```
# Override default composer dependencies to be loaded from inside docker. This is used because
# loading files over mapped volumes is really slow on WSL 2.
require_once "/var/www/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Simply use the `vendor` dir inside docker image.

### index.php

```
$fixFile = "../vendor-override.php";

if (file_exists($fixFile))
    require_once $fixFile;
else
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
    
...
```

If `vendor-override.php` file is detected it is used instead of the one from the project root. This makes sure the `index.php` loads dir inside of the docker image which is way faster.

### composer.json

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Namespace\\": ["src"]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Simple autoloading setup maps "Namespace" to `src` dir in project root.

### Key things to note

- index.php loads `vendor-override.php` instead of vendor from proect root
- PSR-4 autoloading is solved by linking

## Downside

The downside is you have to build docker image every time you update dependencies.

Comment: nice, but really sketchy, hope there is another way

Answer (score 1):

By default, opcache is not enabled in docker container php:8.0-apache.
Add in dockerfile:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
COPY ./opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini
```

Create file opcache.ini:

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable=1
; 0 means it will check on every request
; 0 is irrelevant if opcache.validate_timestamps=0 which is desirable in production
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000
opcache.memory_consumption=192
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=10
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=16
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

Comment: why minus :( ???

Comment: can you explain this more?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php

Answer (score 1):

I just enabled Hyper-V from PowerShell:

```bash
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Restarted and now it works reasonably good. I have not changed anything else whatsoever.

See more info about how to enable Hyper-V [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v).

Comment: Restarted *what*? Hyper-V? The containers? Docker Desktop? The whole machine?

Answer (score 0):

One more option that allows a workaround for this type of case is Docker's [Compose Watch](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/). It allows you to place files in a container and use watch to update them when the project is edited on the host. To achieve this, we could use a configuration like:

```
version: '3'
services:
    php:        
        build: 
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
        develop:
          watch:
            - path: ./project_source
              target: /var/www
              action: sync
```

Also, note that we need to copy files to the container during the build. The watch functionality will only copy changed files from the main folder and its subfolders. To start, we should use:

```
docker compose watch
```