# Laravel is suspiciously slow (fresh app, everything is by default)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sail

I work with Windows 10 (WSL 2).
My hardware is:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.60 GHz
RAM 8.00GB
SSD

Actually, this is a game laptop (MSI GL 65 95CK) if you are interested.

I decided to install Laravel, went to documentation and implemented described steps:

1. In WSL terminal (I use Ubuntu) `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql,redis" | bash`
2. `cd example-app && /vendor/bin/sail up`

I went to browser and realized that the main page took almost 1 second to render! Sometimes even two seconds!
[image]

I thought, "ok, maybe the framework is in a not optimized mode. Debug and so on", and decided to turn `APP_DEBUG` in `.env` to `false`. I also removed all routes and put this instead:

`Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class, 'test']);`

Before this, I created the `TestController`:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test() {
        return response()->json([
            'name' => 'Abigail',
            'state' => 'CA',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then I run `php artisan optimaze`, open in browser `http://localhost/api`

and the result is a big sorrow:

[image]

Why 800ms? I did not do anything.
Ok, I decided just to rename the `index.php` file in the `public` folder to `index2` for example, put new one `index.php` with the array printing just to test whether this is a Laravel problem or this is just an infrastructure issue.

New `index.php`:

[image]

Much better!
Then I thought, "let's compare with another framework, for example with .NET Core". And I made a very simple Web Api project.
Controller:

```
namespace MockWebApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("")]
    public class MainController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("test")]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                Test = "hello world!!!"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Ok, you can argue that this is a compiled language. I decided to check with Node.js and Express:

Code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({"test": "123"})
});
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, Node as fast as C# in this case.

So, what is wrong with Laravel? Did I miss something in installation?

### UPDATE

I raised Laravel without Sail. My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - internal

  nginx:
    build:
      context: docker/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

Nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

ADD ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

php-fpm Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget git unzip \
    && apt-get install libpq-dev -y 

RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/installer -O - -q \
    | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer --quiet

RUN groupadd -r -g 1000 developer && useradd -r -u 1000 -g developer developer

USER developer
WORKDIR /var/www
```

I did not get any performance improvement(

Comment: How do you run your php server? What version? is xDebug on? can you try it without ssl? Most probably it's not the laravel setup, but the webserver / php setup that is causing it to be slow.

Comment: Everything was according to documentation. It means, I used Sail https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail 
Just go to this url https://laravel.build/example-app and u will see what Sail runs.

Comment: I just want to say that I did not have installed PHP/Server or something from the stack. I used Sail.

Comment: As a framework, there _is_ some overhead too, i.e. if you did a basic `index.php` file, without laravel, and served it via `localhost/index.php` (direct reference, no routing, etc.), it would be faster than Laravel. You could try caching (config/route caching) locally so help speed things up too. All that being said, not sure what you expect from this question; what is your expected outcome? Advice on how to speed up Laravel? Recommendations on a different framework to use? Something else?

Comment: a little overhead is normal - yes, but from my experience 1 sec for nothing is way too long. I never worked with sail so I cannot help here any further - sorry.

Comment: @TimLewis I just want to understand why I just installed the framework and already have some performance problem. It should be easy to run something simple, like in my example.

Comment: So I got curious and did a fresh sail setup. Default page loaded in 76ms. The json string in your test function loaded in 49ms. So, something in your setup must be the culprit.

Comment: @user3532758 thank you! And what operating system do you use? Did you set up something additionally (I mean PHP/web server)? Just all according to Laravel documentation?

Comment: This is windows 10. Using WSL2. Hardware is inferior to yours; i7 6500U 2.50GHz 16GB RAM SSD and, yes, sail with mysql setup all according to laravel documentation.

Comment: @user3532758 thank you. Something is interfering to work the PHP stack on my machine. Strange.

Comment: Yeah definitely. I just tested one of the huge websites I have on my machine, which calls external resources as well without any optimisations or caching. It also took only 200ms to load everything.

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one who faced with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036490/docker-is-extremely-slow-when-running-laravel-on-nginx-container-wsl2

Comment: So the problem is not in Laravel and not in PHP.  WSL2 is the reason

Comment: Ah I thought so! Were you running docker from the windows filesystem?

Comment: @user3532758 yes) Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036490/docker-is-extremely-slow-when-running-laravel-on-nginx-container-wsl2 ? 
My question is duplicate. The answer what is going on is over there. So, the conclusion here is to use Linux for Linux friendly things (like PHP for example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker is extremely slow when running Laravel on Nginx container wsl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036490/docker-is-extremely-slow-when-running-laravel-on-nginx-container-wsl2)