# Laravel with Sail and Docker, really slow

Tags: php, laravel, docker, wsl-2, laravel-sail

I tried to run a fresh Laravel 9.2 project with Laravel Sail in Docker. (contains WSL2), and the index page is loaded in 2sec. For an existing project where I tried Sail to run on Docker, it takes ~7sec instead of 0.3 as it takes on Laravel Homestead.

I find a similar post [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036490/docker-is-extremely-slow-when-running-laravel-on-nginx-container-wsl2) , but is still not working.

- I have tried Ubuntu, Ubuntu 20.04 is the same. On Ubuntu 18 I don't have
  in /mnt/c disk not sure why.
- I have tried to run on wsl 1, and disable ***Use the WSL 2 based engine*** from Docker, and to enable ***Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS***, but then when I try to run `./vendor/bin/sail up` is not working anymore "Docker is not running", from what I checked on [Laravel page](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail) , I need WSL2.

***docker-compose.yml*** (generated by Laravel Sail)

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Comment: No, Windows 10. I forgot to specify that.

Comment: Did you find an elegant solution to this? My Development progress is slowed down a lot... taking 20-30 seconds to load a localhost page, its frustrating

Answer (score 2):

Where are your project files located?

If you installed your laravel project with composer and they are on your c drive or other local disk this could be the problem.

Put the project files in your linux home directory
e.g.\wsl$\Ubuntu\home[username][your project]

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the section

```
 volumes:
   - '.:/var/www/html'
```

Its a bind mount to windows filesystem.

Don't put it on a windows filesystem tho as it will slow down things a lot.

Put your docker-compose.yml file inside the WSL2 for example `\\wsl$\Debian\home\[username]\projects\[your_project]`

And then compose it up from there, it will be much faster.

This is a common WSL2 rule, if u use host bind mount `volumes` section for any service - store your source code in the WSL 2 filesystem not on windows fs. Its not needed for docker managed volumes.

You dont need to change anything else, nor should, leave wsl2 engine enabled and use only wsl2.

Comment: I tried to change the volume, but when I run ./vendor/ bin/sail up, I get 'Could not open input file: /var/www/html/artisan'

Comment: Im sorry i cannot help u with Laravel Sail, maybe ask their support or discord, but it is docker and this is why it is super slow, u need to put the docker-compose.yml inside the WSL2 filesystem and run it from there. Also this is the recommended setup from laravel itself https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows so i dont know why it isn't working for you.