# Is there a way to extract to a different directory then vendor/composer

Tags: composer-php

When using composer in docker on Windows access to filesystem is rather slow. It would be great if the initial export to tmp directory could be located outside of the mounted FS - ideally in a custom directory, not vendor/composer/[hash] but for example /var/cache/composer or something.

Is there a configuration flag for it or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker is extremely slow when running Laravel on Nginx container wsl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036490/docker-is-extremely-slow-when-running-laravel-on-nginx-container-wsl2)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think so. I have non WSL2 setup

Comment: also the suggestions don't help - like copy vendor - I can't install outside of container because of special deps that need php modules, also IDE in windows won't see the dependencies and index them, etc.

Comment: The nuclear option is to move everything inside WSL2 (run IDE and git client in WSL) but that's a lot of work.