# Laravel slow within Docker when project files are not in image

Tags: laravel, docker

My desktop is fresh install of Windows 11 (i9, 128GB RAM, SSDs), running Docker (v20.10.24) and Docker Desktop (v4.18) in WSL2 mode.  I develop in Visual Studio Code (v1.77.3) and attach to the projects development folder.

In Docker, I have a Laravel project, with the project development files mapped to a local desktop location in my docker-compose:

```
volumes:
 
   - ./:/var/www/html
```

This gave me 10 second page load times with just "Hello World" as the content, but still loading all my vendor files in the background I assume.  So i changed to this in my Dockerfile:

```
COPY /project/ /var/www/html
```

And from there I got load times measure in milliseconds.  But of course my project development files are 'trapped' within the docker image now.

I cant run PHP on my Desktop, I need to run it within Docker.  Is there a general better workflow or development process that will give me performance and flexibility in development?

Note: I am running Apache, not artisan serve.

Comment: what is the current folder `./` referring to? if you run `pwd`, what is the absolute path to that `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Is this the same issue as [Docker is extremely slow when running Laravel on Nginx container wsl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036490/docker-is-extremely-slow-when-running-laravel-on-nginx-container-wsl2)?  That has a couple of suggestions around different setup, but fundamentally the bind-mount mechanism can be rather slow using Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Could you map the volume like this:

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: ./
    target: /var/www/html
```

Comment: this halved the times of my requests, thanks.  BUt still not in milliseconds. The comment from @david maze got me in the right direction.